# Web client communicate with gRPC server

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

I have a c++ service which I intend to expose using a gRPC server. What is the way a web browser would communicate with the gRPC server? I am using angularJS for the front end.

I look at [grpc documentation](http://www.grpc.io/docs/). But can't find information on browser support.

[image: Image taken from https://dzone.com/articles/grpc-sample-in-c-and-python]

Comment: Can you elaborate on the question ? I thought the docs were pretty straightforward. Maybe you have not used rpc before ?

Comment: @RomainHippeau I updated the question. Yes, I haven't used gRPC before. I updated the question. In short, how can communicate to a gRPC server from web browser?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35065875/how-to-bring-a-grpc-defined-api-to-the-web-browser http://www.grpc.io/faq/ it looks like you are going to need a translation service. If not get supports object serialization and rpc. It is a steep learning curve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bring a gRPC defined API to the web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35065875/how-to-bring-a-grpc-defined-api-to-the-web-browser)

Answer (score 6):

i used grpc gateway. Many large projects use it too.
It translated GRPC RPC into Rest / JSON.

https://github.com/gengo/grpc-gateway

Comment: I use grpc-java for server and I know grpc-gateway is created in go. so can I use it in my project? how?

Answer (score 4):

[How to bring a gRPC defined API to the web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35065875/how-to-bring-a-grpc-defined-api-to-the-web-browser) http://www.grpc.io/faq/ it looks like you are going to need a translation service. If not gwt supports object serialization and rpc. It is a steep learning curve.

Answer (score 2):

With some more recently released technology (and also [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45335922/1370384) on the question that is a possible duplicate): I've used the `grpcwebproxy` (on top of a Python grpc server) and the corresponding `ts-protoc-gen` plugin from Improbable. It "talks" gRPC directly between client / server (following the preliminary web-spec), without using REST or JSON translation, and allows you to use your `proto` files client-side as well as server-side:

https://improbable.io/games/blog/grpc-web-moving-past-restjson-towards-type-safe-web-apis

https://github.com/improbable-eng/grpc-web

Answer (score 1):

Now gRPC web is available to use.

https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web